# Improving ST_Intersects performance in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, performance, st-intersects, code-review

I have the following query, but it takes a long time to run. I tried creating an index, but there hasn't been much improvement. Any suggestions?

```
CREATE INDEX temp_clusters_geom_idx
ON temp_clusters
USING GIST(concave_hull)

CREATE INDEX temp_da_geom_idx
ON temp_da
USING GIST(concave_hull)

SELECT 
c.id, 
ST_Area(di.concave_hull) - ST_Area(ST_Difference(di.concave_hull,c.concave_hull)) as internal_area,
(ST_Area(di.concave_hull) - ST_Area(ST_Difference(di.concave_hull,c.concave_hull))) * cast(di."Income" as float) as overall_weighted_area,
c.concave_hull
FROM temp_clusters c
JOIN
    (
        SELECT d.concave_hull,"Income" 
        FROM temp_da d 
        JOIN temp_da_income i on d."DAUID" = i."DAUID"
        WHERE "Income" is NOT NULL
    )di
ON ST_Intersects(c.concave_hull, di.concave_hull) 
WHERE category = 'hexagon'
```

here, `temp_da` size is 57932 and `temp_clusters` is 34964
And, this part is quite fast as well:

```
SELECT d.concave_hull,"Income" 
        FROM temp_da d 
        JOIN temp_da_income i on d."DAUID" = i."DAUID"
```

**Query plan:**

```
"Gather  (cost=3078.30..595214897.33 rows=28033277 width=1555)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2078.30..592410569.63 rows=11680532 width=1555)"
"        Hash Cond: (d.""DAUID"" = i.""DAUID"")"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..2231655.66 rows=12575461 width=8101)"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on temp_clusters c  (cost=0.00..12552.37 rows=14636 width=1539)"
"                    Filter: (category = 'hexagon'::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using idx_temp_da_concave_hull on temp_da d  (cost=0.28..151.56 rows=6 width=6562)"
"                    Index Cond: (concave_hull && c.concave_hull)"
"                    Filter: st_intersects(c.concave_hull, concave_hull)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1405.36..1405.36 rows=53813 width=15)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on temp_da_income i  (cost=0.00..1405.36 rows=53813 width=15)"
"                    Filter: (""Income"" IS NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: please add the `explain` output for your query

Comment: "long time" isn't as descriptive as it could be, but it looks like you forgot to index temp_da_income on ("DAUID","Income")

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be two "expensive" operations in the explain output, which are easy to fix.

`category = 'hexagon'` (12552) and `""Income"" IS NOT NULL` (1405)

So put an index on `category` and mark `Income` as Not NULL (unless it is nullable, in which case add an index with Nulls at the end).

Finally, most of your time is going on:

```
Hash Join  (cost=2078.30..592410569.63 rows=11680532 width=1555)"
```

where Postgres does the final join, have you made `DAUID` a primary key on both tables?

Answer (score 3):

try forcing a bounding box intersect before the actual geom intersect like this. if its a small number of features it likely wont have much of an impact but its many complex geometries it should help

```
SELECT 
c.id, 
ST_Area(di.concave_hull) - ST_Area(ST_Difference(di.concave_hull,c.concave_hull)) as internal_area,
(ST_Area(di.concave_hull) - ST_Area(ST_Difference(di.concave_hull,c.concave_hull))) * cast(di."Income" as float) as overall_weighted_area,
c.concave_hull
FROM temp_clusters c
JOIN
    (
        SELECT d.concave_hull,"Income" 
        FROM temp_da d 
        JOIN temp_da_income i on d."DAUID" = i."DAUID"
        WHERE "Income" is NOT NULL
    )di
ON c.cancave_hull && di.concave_hull AND ST_Intersects(c.concave_hull, di.concave_hull) 
WHERE category = 'hexagon'
```

Comment: `ST_Intersects` automatically includes a bounding box operator call, so this should not be necessary.  (You can see the query plan includes an `index Scan` using `&&`.)

Comment: I've actually had queries which failed to use the PostGIS index without an explicit `&&` operation. The processing time difference was measured in days. Sometimes "should not" is not enough to protect performance.

Comment: explicitly adding the bounding box has sped but many queries for me as well.